# jquery-mobile google maps set marker location from address instead of earth long langtitude?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

How to correctly set just the location based on address instead of position?
As a sidenode im try to set it to a decent zoom value. Does anyone know where in the docs this is mentioned?

Using below code but cannot find any reference on how to set the location of the marker based on "address, street, city, state, country )

```
$(document).live("pageshow", "#map_page", function() {
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'bounds': true}).click(function() {
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use google geocoding API to convert addresses into latlng objects and
  then plot the position in map
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/
- Make use of `fitBounds` method for adjusting the zoom level based on
  the points you are plotting.
  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: Trying the examples from these docs don't work for the jquery mobile google maps edition though

Comment: google maps normal is incompatible with jquery mobile google maps so no examples work no matter wich one tried.